# Can't install required dependencies for Discord version 0.0.21

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, deb

I am attempting to install the Discord app on my computer so I can make it say I'm playing Minecraft. When I attempt to install discord-0.0.21.deb, it comes back with the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 discord : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
           Depends: libc++1 but it is not installable
           Recommends: libappindicator1 but it is not installable or
                       libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I attempted to install the missing dependencies, but it says the packages could not be found. Why is this?

System info: 2012 MacBook Pro i5, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

If any other information is necessary, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, I am just curious, how does Ubuntu work with this Macbook Pro? Do wireless/grapics card/webcam/microphone work flawlessly?

Comment: Yep, it all works great. For a short time the microphone stopped; however, the issue has now been fixed.